# web site hosting as application in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I have an web Application. My application work properly when i hosting as site(www.example.com). But when try to host as a application under my site (www.example.com/everway) css file & javascript (window.location.href) not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asset URLs when hosted at www.example.com/everway would look like www.example.com/everway/javascripts/application.js, right?

www.example.com/javascripts/application.js and www.example.com/everway/javascripts/application.js are not the same.

Does your application account for that difference?